# Prevent scroll div when wheel a input range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `div`, fixed height, and scroll.
But inside this div, have an input range. When I fire the wheel event then the scroll of the div is also triggered, so is there any way to block this scrolling while I'm wheeling?

Here is an example of this

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0);
  const onwheelVolumne = (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      setVolume(volume + 10 > 100 ? 100 : volume + 10);
    } else {
      setVolume(volume - 10 < 0 ? 0 : volume - 10);
    }
    return false;
  };
  return (
    <Box
      border="1px solid #ccc"
      padding={2}
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      height={200}
      overflow="auto"
    >
      <input type="range" value={volume} onWheel={onwheelVolumne} />
      {Array(10)
        .fill(10)
        .map((i, idx) => (
          <p key={idx}>samnple</p>
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sun-lfyhlr?file=/src/App.js:23-738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `onMouseEnter` to detect and add event to prevent scroll

```
const [mouseEnter, setMouseEnter] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mouseEnter) {
      return;
    }
    window.addEventListener("wheel", preventScroll, { passive: false });
    return () => window.removeEventListener("wheel", preventScroll, false);
  }, [mouseEnter]);

  const preventScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
  };

  return (
    <Box
      border="1px solid #ccc"
      padding={2}
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      height={200}
      overflow="auto"
    >
      <input
        type="range"
        value={volume}
        onWheel={onwheelVolumne}
        onMouseEnter={() => setMouseEnter(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setMouseEnter(false)}
      />
      {Array(10)
        .fill(10)
        .map((i, idx) => (
          <p key={idx}>samnple</p>
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to <s>toggle the scroll event of parent div</s> toggle the focus of input range:

```js
  const ref = useRef();

  return (
    <Box
      border="1px solid #ccc"
      padding={2}
      display="flex"
      flexDirection="column"
      height={200}
      overflow={'auto'}
    >
      <input ref={ref} type="range" value={volume} onWheel={onwheelVolumne} onMouseEnter={() => {
       ref.current?.focus();
      }} onMouseLeave={() => {
        ref.current?.blur();
      }}/>
      {Array(10)
        .fill(10)
        .map((i, idx) => (
          <p key={idx}>samnple</p>
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
```

Comment: I have tested it but not working

Comment: Yeah, I think if I toggle it to focus the input with `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` it will be ok